# Can't get bash escapes to work using ssh, nohup & netcat

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, netcat, nohup

Trying to work through an annoying problem here that is certainly solvable if I could just find the correct sequences to escape properly.

Scenario: I have a script that is used with zfs send/recv and to get the best performance in local networks, I want the script to connect to the receiving machine, spawn a netcat listener piping into zfs recv which I will then send to from the source script.

I construct the command similar to:

```
rcmd="nohup nc -l -p $NCPORT|zfs recv $destfs > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

And launch it with:

```
ssh -f $RHOST "${rcmd}"
```

And then start the send stream with:

```
zfs send $locallastsnap | nc $RHOST $NCPORT
```

On the receiving end, I see it spawn two processes

```
bash -c nohup nc -l -p 12739|zfs recv backup/data
nc -l -p 12739
```

So somewhere along the line, the globbing is losing the pipe connection to the recv command and the nohup stdout/err redirection.

Comment: I don't believe you are supposed to see redirections in `ps`/etc. output. They aren't part of the running command they are part of the shell invocation of it.

Comment: OK - that explains the missing 2>&1, but I'm still stuck on the rest. I've tried a myriad of different escaping mechanisms without any success.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the posted code. The redirects should appear in the `ps` line for bash, since they're part of a quoted string passed to bash as an argument. ps may be truncating the command line in its output. Consider checking `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` for the bash process's PID to see what was actually passed to bash.

Comment: Regarding lack of the `zfs` command, try running your ssh command without the redirections, so you can see any errors from the command. Bash may be failing to start zfs, or zfs may be printing an error message and exiting early.

Comment: I have the script print all of the commands so I can follow along and if I launch them manually, everything works perfectly. Sigh. I get a broken pipe on the sending side as there's no ZFS recv process listening and then the cleanup code kills the nc process, but no early errors on the receiving side with redirections off.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be having a problem with your pipeline.  You see this command on the remote machine:

```
bash -c nohup nc -l -p 12739|zfs recv backup/data
```

But you want it to say:

```
bash -c "nohup nc -l -p 12739|zfs recv backup/data"
```

Otherwise, I think your pipeline will wait for bash to exit and pipe the output to zfs.

So, maybe try adding these quotes yourself:

```
rcmd="\"nohup nc -l -p $NCPORT|zfs recv $destfs > /dev/null 2>&1\""
```

Comment: I don't think so. If `-c` didn't see the whole string you wouldn't see it all on that process listing (you would just see the part before the pipe). It is unfortunate that it looks confusing but that's a side-effect of where quoting is removed.